# How can I apply ripple just like whatsapp attachment dialog?

Tags: android, transition, ripple

I know how to apply ripple effect as background on views so they are triggered on touch event. but that's not what I'm looking for.

what I want is the following :

I have a view (LinearView) with children (ImageButtons). this view is hidden at the begining.
when the user clicks the icon on action bar, the view should be visible with ripple transition. just like when you click attach icon in whatsapp.

[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETXfY.png)

Comment: That's not a ripple effect - it's called a [Circular Reveal](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal) Effect.

Comment: thanks for the source, but does that works on pre lolipop androids? I'm using appCompat 21.

Comment: Unfortunately no (at least not with the tools and api's that Google provides us). I think even WhatsApp doesn't show this effect on pre-Lollipop versions.

Comment: thank you , I just tested the example on android developers site and it worked on my device. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading the images from local resources, you can use the [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library.